# How to build PyQt6 app designed as MVC with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyqt6

I recently coded a program to extract subtitles from video and audio files. The interface is written with PyQt6 and I have problems with the compilation. I can't use fbs because I'm on Python 3.10. I get a **TypeError 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer** using pyinstaller traditionally but everything works when I run with the Python interpreter. Here is the architecture of my project and the main file is the view.pyc file. You can directly access the code on Github via this [link](https://github.com/ParfaitD9/subtitler).

```bash
reader
|-- README.md
|-- __init__.py
|-- assets
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- chunks
|   |-- icon.svg
|   |-- py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- subtitler.py
|   |-- screenshot_subtitler_1.png
|   |-- state.cfg
|   |-- ui
|   |   `-- subtitler.ui
|   `-- user.cfg
|-- controller.py
|-- models.py
|-- requirements.txt
|-- tests.py
|-- tree.txt
|-- view.pyw
```

I need command to tape build this project as executable.

Comment: From where do you get the error, from the compiling process or while running the binary file?

Comment: Not really, it don't answer my question. I get this error from the compiling process.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Sorry, I finally found. I was using pyinstaller-3 while current version is pyinstaller-5. Everything is working fine now.